# Mongoid sessions not found

Tags: mongodb, sinatra, mongoid

Trying out a Sinatra | Mongoid 3. I run into the following error, whenever I attempt to save to the database.

```
Mongoid::Errors::NoSessionsConfig: 
Problem:
 No sessions configuration provided.
Summary:
Mongoid's configuration requires that you provide details about each session that can be connected to, and requires in the sessions config at least 1 default session to exist.
Resolution:
    Double check your mongoid.yml to make sure that you have a top-level sessions key with at least 1 default session configuration for it. You can regenerate a new mongoid.yml for assistance via `rails g mongoid:config`.

Example:
 development:
    sessions:
     default:
        database: mongoid_dev
     hosts:
      - localhost:27017

from /Users/rhodee/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mongoid-3.0.13/lib/mongoid/sessions/factory.rb:61:in `create_session'
```

I've already confirmed the following:

- Mongoid.yml file is loaded
- The hash contains correct environment and db name

Using pry the return value from the `Mongoid.load!` method returns:

```
=> {"sessions"=>
 {"default"=>
 {"database"=>"bluster",
 "hosts"=>["localhost:27017"],
 "options"=>{"consistency"=>"strong "}}}}
```

If it's any help check, I've added the app.rb file and mongoid.yml file as well.

**App.rb**

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'mongoid'
require 'pry'
require 'routes'
require 'location'

configure :development do
 enable :logging, :dump_errors, :run, :sessions
 Mongoid.load!(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), "config", "mongoid.yml"))
end
```

**Mongoid.yml**

```
 development:
   sessions:
     default:
      database: bluster
      hosts:
        - localhost:27017
      options:
       consistency: strong
```

Answer (score 1):

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'mongoid'
require 'pry'
require 'routes'

configure :development do
  enable :logging, :dump_errors, :run, :sessions
  Mongoid.load!(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), "config", "mongoid.yml"))
end

get '/db' do
  "db: " <<  Mongoid.default_session[:moped].database.inspect
end
```

I put together an example, and it is working just fine for me. Probably your problem is something else, like the config file not having read access or something else. Anyways my config file is identical as yours and this is my sinatra file, and it works fine.